# Trying to get blobs using Emgu on Raspberry Pi

Tags: image-processing, .net-core, raspbian, opencv3.0, emgucv

I have a.NetCore app.
I am using Emgu CV framework for image processing.
I am targetting the Rapsberry Pi using the Raspbian OS.
I am capturing images from the camera.
I am comparing previous and current images. Working out the difference. Applying a threshold. Converting too GrayScale and then to a biary image.
Emgu is not supported on .NetCore.
So trying to make it work myself.
I have made some of the Emgu functions that work on Windows Desktop work on Raspain ARM.

I am trying to get blobs from the binary image.

using the Detect method will give a segmentation fault.
So trying to work with ConnectedComponents.

I have this:

```
Mat AbsDiffThresholded = new Mat(288, 360,  DepthType.Cv8U, 1);

public static byte GetByteConnectedComponentsFrom2DArray( int minBlobSize)
{
    VectorOfVectorOfPoint contours = new VectorOfVectorOfPoint();
    double area;
    int n;
    CvInvoke.FindContours(AbsDiffThresholded, contours, null, RetrType.External, ChainApproxMethod.ChainApproxSimple);

    n = contours.Size;

    for (var i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        if (CvInvoke.ContourArea(contours[i]) >= minBlobSize)
        {
            return 1;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Which does give me the areas of white pixels.

But, I did to know the density of the white pixels in the area.

If I try to use

```
var M = CvInvoke.Moments(c);
 int cx = (int)(M.M10 / M.M00);
 int cy = (int)(M.M01 / M.M00)
```

it will error on the Cv.Invoke line with segmentation fault.

My think is that coupled with the x,y coordinates i can get establish the ROI and from there i can get the white pixel density.

i can get all to work easily on desktop but like I said I am on Raspian ARM Processor using .NetCore c#

;

Comment: Surely the idea of the RaspberryPi is open source software (Raspbian + OpenCV) on open source hardware. Why would anyone want to run proprietary C#, and proprietary .NetAnything on it? Sorry, with the best will in the world, I don't understand.

Comment: @MarkSetchell Hi, thanks for your comment.  I am always willing to learn things. I am very much interested in your thoughts here.  What is wrong wiith trying to write a commercial app on a small hardward footprint woth open source OS like Raspbian? Windows IoT 10 OS is free to use and ditribute. Why should the choice of hardware and/or OS be a deciding factor to write a commefcial app. Most security cameras are written withing linux and sold on. Help me to understand ur viewpoint in case i am making a terrible mistake (+1 for you angle on all this btw)

Comment: @MarkSetchell sorry to add. I realy do not know c++ but familia with c#. in case i misinterpreted ur comment. thanks :)

Comment: You are obviously at liberty to do as you wish and I wouldn't presume to tell anyone what to do. It just seemed to me that you are going against the flow trying to make a Raspberry Pi work in a Windows kind of way when the vast majority of folk, whose questions I try to help with on StackOvefflow, use an open source Python/C++ approach. I wish you good luck and every success with your project.

Comment: @MarkSetchell I was not insulted at all btw.  I understand ur point. I was thinking of keeping the price unit as cheap as pos for my end client. I have got the ASUS Tinkerboard here as well. The netcore is opensource though. Thanks for taking the time to comment. I take all view points on board. Thanks again